# Проблема с русскими символами в имени файла

Tags: кодировка, php

Проблема с кириллицей. Есть файл-картинка "фото.jpg". Если напишем так:

```
<img src="фото/jpg" />
```

то все работает, а если через скрипт

```
$file = scandir($dir);
echo "<img src='" . $file[2] . "' />";
```

то ничего не получается, потому что php  кодирует имя файла в что-то типа F%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF и выводит **not found** . Это наверное банальная проблема, но наверное у меня не хватает мозгового вещества для ее решения.

Comment: Это особенности кодировки файловых систем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот баг, проявляющийся в разных ипостасях, исправлен в PHP 7.1. Смотрите здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591374/227924 а так же в англоязычной версии. В PHP версиях, предшествующих 7.1, используeтся однобайтное Windows API, и бороться с этим тяжело или совсем никак. Наверное большинство вопросов на тему кодировки имён файлов можно маркировать как дубликаты.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте перекодировать имя файла в utf-8 или cp1251 через iconv
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php

Comment: iconv ("cp1251","utf-8") - тогда пхп перестает видеть латинские символы, по-моему.

Comment: @iamsalnikov, благодарю, что еще раз носом натыкали. Я эту функцию до этого пробовал использовать, но видно что-то не так пошло. Попробовал еще раз - все ок! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

а у вас кодировка какая?
Попробуйте в начале скрипта: `ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');`

Или так: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: @markgenuine, ini_set устанавливает кодировку страниц, а не файлов. Все ок, помогло iconv

Comment: ой точно, че то тупанул, сонный наверное:-D