# Создание скриптом файлов с русскими названиями

Tags: php, кодировка

Есть скрипт который создаёт файлы и имеет кодировку utf-8.При русских символах, названия файлов имеют кракозябры. Как это решить? Тестили на линуксе и на винде

Comment: Интересно, вы для чего такие имена файлов создаете? С русскими буквами в именах.

Comment: Вы уверены, что системная локаль у вас UTF-8 (как минимум в Linux) ?

Comment: @Борис Ну спросили у поддержки, локаль c1251, но что-то не пашет

Comment: @МихаилХалупов: не пашет даже с использованием iconv? или что именно не пашет?

Comment: Как минимум два дубликата этого вопроса существуют: - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600025/227924 - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591374/227924 Thanks.

Comment: По первой ссылке речь идёт об автоматическом URL Encoding, а не «кракозябрах». По второй — автор выполнял перекодировку, но целевая кодовая страница не содержала нужных символов.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функцию [iconv](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php). При создании файла, например:

```
<?php

$filename = @iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", 'ИМЯ_ФАЙЛА_НА РУССКОМ');
file_put_contents($filename, 'КАКОЙ-ТО ТЕКСТ');

?>
```

---

**UPD:** Конечная кодировка может отличатся.

Comment: На линуксах тоже кодировка windows-1251 используется? :)

Comment: Это зависит он выбранного окружения. Чаще нет, но при корявой настройке - да. У меня было несколько раз, при заказе VPS, что кодировка cp1251 (