# Создать файл с немецкими умлаутами в имени в русской windows

Tags: php

Необходимо программно из php создать файл в русской windows, содержащий немецкие символы. Русские имена отлично создаются после перекодировки из UTF-8 в Windows-1251. Но с именами типа Sprächt, Kœnig и т.д. возникают проблемы. В 1251 нет таких символов. Причем просто средствами проводника windows файл с таким именем создается. Каким образом можно создать такой файл?

Comment: в php не то что с немецкими ... с русскими то именами проблема при обработке в windows!

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь все понимаю, но тем не менее задача есть

Comment: я долго бился с решением переименования файлов с кирилицей в названии и у меня ничего не вышло.... если только не использовать  win api из php что довольно специфично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 7.1 поддерживает имена файлов в UTF-8 независимо от кодовой страницы системы. Отвечено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525830/how-do-i-use-filesystem-functions-in-php-using-utf-8-strings/38466772#38466772), подробности в [UPGRADING](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1/UPGRADING#L416).

В предыдущих версия PHP, можно использовать расширение com_dotnet, поставляемое с ядром PHP. Или [wfio](https://github.com/kenjiuno/php-wfio), доступно на github.

Thanks.